Issue with Odoo Website Checkout Process: Redirecting to Error Page
I'm currently facing an issue with the checkout process on my Odoo website. When customers attempt to checkout, instead of proceeding to the payment method selection page, they are redirected to an error page (500 Internal Server Error). This issue persists despite my efforts to resolve it by searching online.
500 Internal Server Error

If this error is caused by one of your modifications in the models, you have the option to reset the model to its factory settings.


Address Management
Restore previous version (soft reset). Reset to initial version (hard reset).

QWeb
Message d'erreur :

Error while render the template
ValueError: View 'website_sale.cart_summary' in website 1 not found
Template: website_sale.address
Path: /t/t[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/t[1]
Node: 
L'erreur s'est produite lors du rendu du modèle website_sale.address et de l'évaluation des expressions suivantes : 

Retraçage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 904, in template_8187
  File "", line 886, in template_8187_content
  File "", line 88, in template_8187_t_call_0
  File "", line 5, in not_found_template
ValueError: View 'website_sale.cart_summary' in website 1 not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/http.py", line 1764, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 133, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/http.py", line 1791, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/http.py", line 1908, in dispatch
    return self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 235, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 224, in _dispatch
    result.flatten()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/http.py", line 1313, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/http.py", line 1305, in render
    return request.env["ir.ui.view"]._render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 442, in _render_template
    return super()._render_template(template, values=values)
  File "/home/odoo/src/enterprise/17.0/web_studio/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1310, in _render_template
    return super(View, self)._render_template(template, values)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 2051, in _render_template
    return self.env['ir.qweb']._render(template, values)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/tools/profiler.py", line 292, in _tracked_method_render
    return method_render(self, template, values, **options)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/17.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 599, in _render
    result = ''.join(rendering)
  File "", line 910, in template_8187
odoo.addons.base.models.ir_qweb.QWebException: Error while render the template
ValueError: View 'website_sale.cart_summary' in website 1 not found
Template: website_sale.address
Path: /t/t[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/t[1]
Node: 


This issue only occurs for regular users or visitors; administrators can proceed through checkout without any problems.
If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights into what might be causing this redirection to the error page, I would greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you in advance for your help!

Could you add which odoo version is affected?

The node <t t-if="mode == ('new', 'billing')"/> is wrong inline python code. It should be <t t-if="mode in ('new', 'billing')"/>.
